# Seeking a better understanding of local memory in CUDA. Where does it live? How much is there? Do I even want to try to make use of it?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

It seems I was misunderstanding local memory by thinking it was fast to access, and that allocating a big array inside a kernel would make use of it, and that would be a good thing. However, after a bit of Googling, it looks like local memory is actually part of global memory and would therefore be slow to access. So now I'm trying to understand exactly what happens when I allocate a large array inside a kernel. Considering that registers are very limited, it's certain that the array wouldn't fit in that space. Does the remainder get spilled over and written to a locally assigned global memory space? Are pieces of it moved in and out of registers as needed? Is this cached in some way that would mitigate the fact that it is global memory if I have to read and write from/to it many times in a kernel? How much memory can a thread actually use for dynamically allocating arrays, and is that limit simply the amount of global memory divided by the number of threads?

I'm using a V100, if it matters for numbers in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Local refers to a *logical* space (at least, that is where I would start).  It happens when you create thread-local variables like this:

```
__global__ void k(int *d, ...){
  int a = *d;
  ...
}
```

The variable `a` is in the [logical local space](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-hierarchy).

Such a variable may have [one or more of several physical backings](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).  The description here may vary slightly on the GPU in use.  To get GPU-to-GPU variations, refer to the [tuning guides](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#programming-guides) for details.

Almost certainly, unless the compiler optimizes it out entirely, the variable will spend some of its lifetime physically backed in a GPU register.  The CUDA programmer has no direct control over this or these choices.

Depending on what else you are doing, the compiler may locate or "spill" this variable to local memory.  The first place this may impact physically is the L1 cache.  It may or may not ever transition from the L1 cache to the L2 cache.  If it finds its way to the L2 cache, it may or may not ever actually get deposited in the "final" physical backing: GPU DRAM memory.

Most CUDA programmers would consider register backing, and probably L1 or L2 backing, to be "fast".  Registers are the fastest.  CUDA programmers might comparatively refer to backing in GPU DRAM memory to be "slow" at least compared to registers.

Again, as a CUDA programmer, you have no direct control over these decisions.  The compiler (and the hardware, when it comes to cache evictions) make the decisions for you.

The decision you have is to use (or not) the logical local space.  The use (or not) of local storage and how it manifests per above can certainly [have an effect](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/implement-2d-matrix-transpose-using-warp-shuffle-without-local-memory/208418) on performance.

> it looks like local memory is actually part of global memory

I would distinguish this by saying the local and global spaces are logically distinct.  However both may ultimately be backed by GPU DRAM memory.  (The global space can also be backed by host memory in some situations, or even the memory resident on a different GPU.)

> Does the remainder get spilled over and written to a locally assigned global memory space?

Possibly, yes (replacing "GPU DRAM" for "global memory" for correctness).  The compiler can tell you about spill loads and stores that it has decided to perform (`-Xptxas -v`).

> Are pieces of it moved in and out of registers as needed?

Yes, scheduled by the compiler, by creating actual instructions to move register contents to memory, or vice versa.

> Is this cached in some way that would mitigate the fact that it is global memory if I have to read and write from/to it many times in a kernel?

Yes, the caches may play a role subject to the specific GPU.  The L2 cache is always involved, the L1 cache may be involved.

> How much memory can a thread actually use for dynamically allocating arrays, and is that limit simply the amount of global memory divided by the number of threads?

Yes, it is [a hardware limit](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability), no, your calculation is not always correct.  There is a hardware upper bound, which can be retrieved with `deviceQuery`, and there is also a [calculation which must be satisified](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-is-the-maximum-cuda-stack-frame-size-per-kerenl/31449).  In a nutshell, the local memory needed per thread cannot exceed the *available* GPU memory divided by the total number of threads that can be active (number of SMs times the maximum number of threads per SM).  The GPU thread may require a stack, and the stack also lives in the logical local space, and impacts the thread's demand for local memory.

Although you didn't directly ask it, there is also a topic around how to get a local array:

```
int a[16];
```

to be completely handled by the compiler in registers.  As indicated above, there are no sufficient conditions for this; it depends on what else you are doing and what the compiler may choose to do.  The compiler generally has a governing heuristic to *maximize the performance of your code*, so the fact that the compiler has not located an array in registers is not necessarily a defect.  There is also no way to "force" this compiler behavior, even if you have met the necessary conditions.

However there are *necessary* conditions for the compiler to possibly locate an array in registers.

- it must be "small" compared to the total registers available.  The maximum registers per thread in CUDA is 255, and this is not always optimal for performance.  An array larger than 255 32-bit words cannot be located in registers.
- all array indices used must be *discoverable at compile time*.  You cannot index into the array using runtime indexing that cannot be determined by the compiler, and expect that array to be resident in registers.  The register space is not "addressable" in this way.  This is one of many reasons that the compiler may choose to aggressively unroll loops.

(The [previous link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/implement-2d-matrix-transpose-using-warp-shuffle-without-local-memory/208418) gives a comparative example of a rather involved case showing one realization where the compiler cannot determine indices at compile time, and another where it can.  I'm not suggesting you should transpose arrays, or transpose this way.  It is merely for understanding/learning.)

Comment: It would seem worthwhile to clarify that (1) local = thread-local (2) the *default* location for a thread-local data object is local memory. The compiler may chose to pull a thread-local data object into a register as an *optimization*. A data object permanently residing in local memory is *not* spilling. Spilling occurs when the compiler desires to place a data object into a register, but runs out of registers, and then *temporarily* pushes that object back into local memory. The CUDA compiler tries to do that intelligently, i.e. minimizing performance impact of spilling.